# Copy cookie from WebView to HttpUrlOpenConnection

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I want to copy cookie which I recived in WEbView and then use them in my urlopenconnections.
By default I use

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

And it works perfectly to handle cookies in my HttpUrlOpenConnection requests. However, somehow it does not attach cookes from webview to my requests.
I tried

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                String cookies = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance()
                        .getCookie(url);
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(url, cookies);
                URI uri = null;
                try {
                    uri = new URI(url);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                CookieManager c = new CookieManager();
                c.getCookieStore().add(uri, cookie);
                Log.d("cookie check", "All the cookies in a string:" + cookies);
                // CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
                CookieHandler.setDefault(с);
            }
}
```

But did not succed. How can I attack cookies from webview to my requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            // super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            final String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);

            url = new URL("yourURL");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
}
```